# what is the complete path of an image in asset folder?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I know a file's relative path:

```
Uri("/Assets/book.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

But what is its absolute path? I want to use it here:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(completePath)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute image path is

```
 ms-appx:///Assets/book.png
```

where ms-appx points to the Local app install folder. 
And you can use as

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/book.png", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: And how to get path starting with "C:\..."?

Answer (score 1):

the absolute path will be

```
ms-appx:///Assets/book.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var resource = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/book.png", UriKind.Relative));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resource.Stream)
{
}
```